# Can I generate Kendo Funnel Chart horizontally?

Tags: css, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz, kendo-chart

I'm trying to generate funnel chart horizontally. I got the demo up and running, but it is vertical. Are there any other options available ?

Got an option with other library:http://www.zingchart.com/gallery/chart/#!horizontal-funnel-styled-guides

But my client wants to use Kendo only and it will be overkill to include other library just for funnel chart

Comment: What have you tried? Can we see the demo? IIRC you can generate it horizontally.

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/funnel-charts/index

Comment: I went through their documentation and could not find any reference to horizontal funnel chart, or any configuration options about orientation.

Comment: I'm looking for something like...
http://www.zingchart.com/gallery/chart/#!horizontal-funnel-styled-guides

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a shot at this anyways, Kendo bar graphs can be generated both horizontally and vertically. You just need to mess with the `type` var in your JS.

**Bar-types are generated horizontally**

```
 $("#yourChart").kendoChart({
     seriesDefaults: {
     //generate as horizontal bar graph
         type: "bar"
     }
 });
```

My guess is you have it set with the **column-type** var like this:

**Column-types are generated vertically**

```
$("#yourChart").kendoChart({
     seriesDefaults: {
      //generate as vertical graph
         type: "column"
     }
  });
```

Kendo funnel charts can not be configured horizontally.

However what you can do is put the chart in a `div` and tell the `div` to flip sideways. Then do the same with the labels, etc.. and reposition everything. It's a bit of a hack, but kind of the only way I see this being possible.

```
#yourDiv{
-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(2700deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(2700deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

Comment: Barcharts, waterfall etc are available in horizontal..I'm particularly looking for horizontal funnel chart..like the one here..http://www.zingchart.com/gallery/chart/#!horizontal-funnel-styled-guides

Comment: @Napster No, you cannot configure them to be horizontal. Here is a **[site](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/funnel-charts/funnel-labels)** that lets you test all the possible layouts for the funnel chart.